# Error al tratar de subir archivo C# jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

El error es el siguiente:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.at VALE_System.Controllers.SistemaController.subirAdjunto(HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload, String modulo, String idRegistro) in C:\Users\EMPHD\Source\Repos\VALE-System\VALE-System\Controllers\SistemaController.cs:line 63

Eh buscado solución por un buen rato y me sigue dando ese mismo error.

En la vista tengo:

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="archivoCC" name="archivoCC"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnAdjuntoCC">Guardar</button>
```

jQuery:

```
        $("#btnAdjuntoCC").click(function () {
        var archivo = ($("#archivoCC"))[0].files[0];
        var modulo = "control de cambios";
        var idRegistro = "1";
        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("archivo", archivo);
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("subirAdjunto", "Sistema")',
            type: "Post",
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Tipo == "success") {
                }
                alert(data.Mensaje)
            }, fail: function (error) { console.log(error); }
        });
    });
```

Y mi controlador lo tengo así:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult subirAdjunto(HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload,string modulo,string idRegistro)
    {
        msg.Seccion = "Adjuntar";
        try
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/Assets/Adjuntos");
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            path = Server.MapPath("~/Assets/Adjuntos/");
            string pathFinal = Path.Combine(path, fileUpload.FileName);
            fileUpload.SaveAs(pathFinal);
            msg.Mensaje = "Subido correctamente";
            msg.Tipo = "success";
            msg.Error = fileUpload.FileName;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            msg.Mensaje = "Se produjo un error al tratar de subir el archivo";
            msg.Tipo = "warning";
            msg.Error = e.ToString();
        }

        return Json(msg, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Por favor alguien que me pueda ayudar.

Comment: Para obtener el archivo lo que debes hacer es `HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload = Request.Files[0];` por que el que envias como parametro te llegara nulo y por eso el error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atento a como estas nombrando tus variables:

```
<input type="file" id="archivoCC" name="archivoCC" />
<input type="submit" value="Save" id="btnSave" />
```

en tu metodo debe coincidir..

```
public string ImageUpload(HttpPostedFileBase archivoCC)
```

por lo demas tu codigo se ve bien.